# Message box in PHP without JS

Tags: php, dialog, box

how can i show a message box with `PHP` codes ? I seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250636/5033303) answer but i don't want to use `JS` code in php .

Comment: you can just output a `<div>` with proper CSS, making it float in front of every other HTML-element on the page. but making it disappear without JS or a full reload would be hard.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann any sample ?

Comment: You don't tell us why you don't want to use Javascript. Without it this question make little sense. Next time you will be asking to do this without CSS, HTML, or a browser. Telling us why Javascript is not allowed also gives us a change to see if you actually understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message boxes you are referring to are created with either JS or HTML/CSS. Since you don't want to use JS, the only alternative is returning an HTML that contains the desired box. Keep in mind that the PHP executes on the server side and just returns a response for each request. Once the response is returned, the PHP is no longer executing.

There are several UI Kits with nice looking boxes. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) is one of the most popular and it's very easy to use. Check their [getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) page to see how to add their CSS in your layout.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the job:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //data checks here...
    //database stuff here...      

    echo '<div class="msg">'
        .'YOUR MESSAGE IN HERE'
        .'</div>';
}
?>

<style>
    .msg {border:1px solid #bbb; padding:5px; margin:10px 0px; background:#eee;}
</style>

<form action="" method="post">
  Name:<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what you are looking for. You need to echo a div with some text inside, and  also echo a checkbox inside your div. In your CSS you can check if the checkbox is checked and stylize it to disappear. The checkbox will act as your close button for the message.

See further information here.[Toggling class without using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543956/toggle-class-on-html-element-without-jquery)